# Facebook Like count in widget Dashing with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, facebook, widget, dashing

To create a monitoring tool with Dashing, I want to display the number of LIKES of Facebook page in a widget. I retrieve the JSON with the necessary information :

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.google.fr%22&format=json

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "share_count": 242039,
         "like_count": 63648,
         "comment_count": 52304,
         "total_count": 357991
      }
   ]
}
```

to view the number of like in a widget as in this example : https://github.com/Ephigenia/foobugs-dashboard#default-dashboard

**How to display only the number of like in Ruby ?**

*I found something similar but uses Nokogiri
https://github.com/Ephigenia/foobugs-dashboard/blob/master/jobs/twitter_user.rb*

Comment: You just want to parse the json and retain "like_count" as text?

Comment: Yes, I just want the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would look like this:

```
    require 'json'

    # make the GET request
    resp = Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.google.fr%22&format=json"))

    # parse the JSON into a ruby hash
    json = JSON.parse(resp)

    # pull the like_count value out of the response
    puts json["data"][0]["like_count"]

    => 63648
```

Comment: Works fine with my widget

Answer (score 1):

You can parse json with the json gem:

```
gem install json
```

In your code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```

Then parse the json like this (the response from facebook):

```
parsed_json = JSON.parse(string)
```

For the like count:

```
parsed_json["data"][0]["like_count"]
```